# Like Does Not Work With Particular Sort of Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have created a stored procedure that is using forms from ASP.NET to create a keyword search of thousands of books we have in our database.

The problem is that I have inherited code from another developer, and must use her code.  I cannot rewrite the stored procedure.

As a result, I have to find a way to add the LIKE operator to the following part of the stored procedure:

```
 Books      = @Books    OR @Books    IS NULL
```

This is because the @Books is the part of the form where the user enters in a keyword search.  I have looked up how to use the LIKE operator in a stored procedure, but nothing applies to this type of code.

The complete stored procedure is listed below:

```
 Create Procedure spSearchAuthors
 @FirstName nvarchar(100) = NULL,
 @LastName nvarchar(100) = NULL,
 @Books nvarchar(50) = NULL
 As
 Begin

 Select FirstName, LastName, Books from Authors where
 (FirstName = @FirstName OR @FirstName IS NULL) AND
 (LastName  = @LastName  OR @LastName  IS NULL) AND
 (Books      = @Books    OR @Books    IS NULL) 
 End
 Go
```

Comment: Erland has provided a lengthy discussion of [dynamic search conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) which should help you improve what you have as well as add the logic you desire.

Answer (score 0):

A `LIKE` has simple syntax: `%`, `_`, `[...]`

In this case you could keep it simple.
By concatinating a `%` to both ends of the string variables.

```
CREATE Procedure spSearchAuthors
 @FirstName NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
 @LastName NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
 @Books NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT FirstName, LastName, Books 
    FROM Authors 
    WHERE (@FirstName IS NULL OR FirstName LIKE '%'+@FirstName+'%') 
      AND (@LastName IS NULL OR LastName  LIKE '%'+@LastName+'%') 
      AND (@Books IS NULL OR Books LIKE '%'+@Books+'%');

END;
GO
```

Using Dynamic SQL is more complicated.

```
CREATE Procedure spSearchAuthors
 @FirstName NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
 @LastName NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
 @Books NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @DynSql NVARCHAR(800);
    DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(100);

    SET @DynSql = N'SELECT FirstName, LastName, Books FROM Authors';

    IF @FirstName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN 
      SET @DynSql += CHAR(10)+'WHERE FirstName LIKE @FirstName';
      SET @FirstName = N'%'+@FirstName+N'%';
    END;

    IF @LastName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
      IF @FirstName IS NULL 
        SET @DynSql += CHAR(10)+'WHERE ';
      ELSE 
        SET @DynSql += CHAR(10)+'AND ';

      SET @DynSql += 'LastName LIKE @LastName';
      SET @LastName = N'%'+@LastName+N'%';
    END;

    IF @Books IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
      IF @FirstName IS NULL AND @LastName IS NULL
        SET @DynSql += CHAR(10)+'WHERE ';
      ELSE
         SET @DynSql += CHAR(10)+'AND ';

      SET @DynSql += 'Books LIKE @Books';
      SET @Books = N'%'+@Books+N'%';
    END;   

    SET @ParmDefinition = N'@FirstName NVARCHAR(102), @LastName NVARCHAR(102), @Books NVARCHAR(52)';  

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynSql, @ParmDefinition, 
      @FirstName = @FirstName, 
      @LastName = @LastName, 
      @Books = @Books;
END;
GO
```